# Eclipse: Set hover image of action

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I create an action and set image for this action

```
Action showErrWarnAct = new Action();
Bundle bundle = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(Activator.class);
URL url = FileLocator.find(bundle, new Path("icons/warning.png"), null);
ImageDescriptor image = ImageDescriptor.createFromURL(url);
showErrWarnAct.setImageDescriptor(image);
```

I want to change the image of action when hover on it. So I use setHoverImageDescriptor

```
showErrWarnAct.setHoverImageDescriptor(image2);
```

But the image does not change when I hover the mouse on it. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the very old Eclipse bug fix [53617](http://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=53617) changed the behavior of Actions (in tool bars at least) so that the hover image is ignored.

The bug does mention a preference value which can be set in the 'plugin_customization.ini' to use the old behavior.